# In Bot Framework, what Unique ID should I use to save session?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using bot framework and I am saving the session.messageAddress so I can send the user a msg later.  I want to track each unique user I get.  In case if they send me another msg again I will know I have already received a msg from them earlier.  What unique ID should I use to identify the user?

I was thinking of using session.message.address.conversation.id, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-identifiers-guide?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

> Every bot and user has an account within each channel. The account contains an identifier (id) and other informative bot non-structural data, like an optional name.
>   Example: "from": { "id": "john.doe@contoso.com", "name": "John Doe" }

You should use `session.message.user.id` to identify the user. Using the conversation id won’t work because the user can start a new conversation with the bot by simply reloading the web chat page and a new conversation id will be generated.

**Edit**

I mistakenly wrote session.from.id to identify the user. The correct way to do it is `session.message.user.id`!

[image: Note that the message object that comes within the session looks like this]

Say that the user John Doe is chatting to the bot through Skype then `message.user.id = "john.doe@contoso.com"` and `message.user.name = "John Doe"`. And there you have it! your unique user id!

The session object will look like this:

```
"session": 
{
    /*...*/
    "message": 
    {
        /*...*/
        "user":
        {
            "id": "john.doe@contoso.com",
            "name": "John Doe"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it give me an error in typescript saying "from" doesn't exist in session.message.from.id

Comment: If you are using webchat, I think you will always get the same userid (the one with which the webchat instance is instantiated - Unless every instance of webchat is instantiated with a unique userid). I advice you to check that, and check the behavior with other channels too.

Comment: Yes, if you are using web chat then it would be your site’s job to handle authorization and pass the user info to the webchat